# Is there a way to override set intersection in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, overriding

i.e. can I define my own '==' method in a class and then make the set intersection operator ('&') use it? Alternatively, is there a way to override the '&' operator itself? 
Can we do something like this?

```
def &(another_object)
   #Code for intersection       
end
```

Comment: Yes, you can define those methods, but it is not clear how you want to define them.

Comment: The documentation for [method names](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names) explains which operators can be defined as a method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `&` is **not an operator**. It’s a syntactic sugar to call the method `&` on LHO, passing RHO as the only argument.

Secondary, I doubt whether copy-pasting your attempt to pry/irb and check whether it works is harder/longer than to post a question here.

```
class MyObject
  def ==(other)
    other.is_a?(MyObject) && self.&(other).empty?
  end

  def &(other)
    []
  end
end

mo1, mo2 = 2.times.map { MyObject.new }
mo1 == mo2 #⇒ true
mo1 == 42  #⇒ false
```

Answer (score 0):

> can I define my own '==' method in a class

Yes, you can:

```
class Foo
  def ==(other)
    # bla
  end
end
```

> and then make the set intersection operator ('&') use it?

Yes, you can:

```
require 'set'

module MySetEqualityExtension
  def &(other)
    reduce([]) {|acc, el| if acc.any? {|a| a == el } then acc else acc << el end }
  end
end

module MySetEquality
  refine Set do
    prepend MySetEqualityExtension
  end
end
```

> Alternatively, is there a way to override the '&' operator itself? 
>   Can we do something like this?
>
> ```
> def &(another_object)
>    #Code for intersection     
> end
> ```

Yes. (As a side-note: it would have taken you less time and effort to just try it instead of asking.)

```
class Foo
  def &(other)
    # bla
  end
end
```

You can do all of what you ask, but the *correct* way would be to simply implement `eql?` and `hash` properly, which is what `Set#&` uses.